# API formation for side loading only required associated data to ember data

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

Please check my previous question
 [EMBER JS - Fetch associated model data from back-end only when required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52714050/ember-js-fetch-associated-model-data-from-back-end-only-when-required)
Related to the above question I need help on API formation in ruby on rails(JSON format: jsonapi.org)
how to form the API for sideloading only `students.records` and link with data already available in ember-data store (school and students)

Comment: could you add some details about the types of data you are wanting in what scenarios? (like example payloads, etc)

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments in the other question, I think you're wanting something like

```
GET /api/students?include=records
```

But you need that filtered to a school, which is where application-specific code can come in, as `{ json:api }` does not dictate how filtering should happen

but, I've used this: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack with much success

So, your new query would be something like:

```
GET /api/students?include=records&q[school_id_eq]=1
```

to get all students and their records for the school with id 1

and then to make this query in ember:

```
store.query('student', {
  include: 'records',
  q: {
    ['school_id_eq']: 1
  }
});
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much
need one more clarification on the linking part 
From the API response do I need to link the records to each student or ember and json API will take care of that
or Do I need to specifically format the API for linking

Comment: ember-data should take care of that for you. all the `records` will show up in the `included` array in the `{ json:api }` payload. All you need to do is specify in your models that a student hasMany records, and a record belongsTo a student (that'd need to be specified on both frontend and backend)

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli JSON API specification reserves `filter` query param for filtering. I think it does not forbid to use another query param (like `q` in your answer) but using `filter` is more inline with spec IMO.

Comment: Right, ransack has an option to change from q to filter. :)